# java.sql.Date cannot express 12-31-2019 without incrementing the year number

Tags: java, date, datepicker

I'm experiencing some frustrating problems when converting to java.sql.Date objects.

Let's say I've picked a date with [JavaFx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX)'s [`DatePicker’](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html), specifically 1-1-2020.
The java.sql.Date object will correctly reflect the selected date:

```
System.out.println("d: " + date1DatePicker.getValue().getDayOfMonth()); // Prints 1
System.out.println("m: " + date1DatePicker.getValue().getMonth()); // Prints 1
System.out.println("y: " + date1DatePicker.getValue().getYear()); // Prints 2020

// This date will be 1-1-2020
java.sql.Date date = Date.valueOf(date1DatePicker.getValue());
```

If, however, I choose one day before, that is, 12-31-2019, the **converted Date object will be wrong:**

```
System.out.println("d: " + date1DatePicker.getValue().getDayOfMonth()); // Prints 31
System.out.println("m: " + date1DatePicker.getValue().getMonth()); // Prints 12
System.out.println("y: " + date1DatePicker.getValue().getYear()); // Prints 2019

// This date will be 12-31-2020 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
java.sql.Date date = Date.valueOf(date1DatePicker.getValue());
```

If I choose 12-30-2019, **the conversion will still fail**:

```
System.out.println("d: " + date1DatePicker.getValue().getDayOfMonth()); // Prints 30
System.out.println("m: " + date1DatePicker.getValue().getMonth()); // Prints 12
System.out.println("y: " + date1DatePicker.getValue().getYear()); // Prints 2019

// This date will be 12-30-2020 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
java.sql.Date date = Date.valueOf(date1DatePicker.getValue());
```

Finally, if I choose 12-29-2019, **the conversion will be correct**:

```
System.out.println("d: " + date1DatePicker.getValue().getDayOfMonth()); // Prints 29
System.out.println("m: " + date1DatePicker.getValue().getMonth()); // Prints 12
System.out.println("y: " + date1DatePicker.getValue().getYear()); // Prints 2019

// This date will be 12-29-2019 ** FINALLY CORRECT **
java.sql.Date date = Date.valueOf(date1DatePicker.getValue());
```

I print java.sql.Date dates using:

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd").format(date));
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: How do you *know* `Date` contains those values? Do you print the object (thus calling `toString`)?

Comment: I print using: new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd").format(date)

Comment: To add to Lard's answer - don't trust the `toString` implementation of date objects - use an appropriate `DateTimeFormatter` and ensure you know the timezone that's been used

Comment: FYI… The terrible `java.sql.Date` Class was supplanted years ago by `java.time.LocalDate` with the adoption of JSR 310.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `java.sql.Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Especially since you can obviously use `LocalDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). For formatting use either a `DateTimeFormatter` or the `toString()`method of your `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are printing it through `YYYY-MM-dd`. The uppercase `Y` represents the *week year*, that means that the year returned is the year that belongs to the week number of that particular date.

Since 30th and 31st of december fall in week 1 of 2020, *that* year number is returned.

The value contained in `Date` is correct; its formatted output is simply confusing. You should use `yyyy-MM-dd` instead.

Comment: You, sir, are my savior. Thank you!

Comment: And you, sir, are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

A [JavaFX `DatePicker`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html) returns its value as a [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html).  This is, as its documentation indicates (emphasis mine):

> A date **without a time-zone** in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12-03.

So when you call `datePicker.getValue()`, you get back one of these.

Then you feed it into [`java.sql.Date#valueOf(LocalDate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf(java.time.LocalDate)), whose documentation indicates that a certain kind of conversion will occur:

> The provided `LocalDate` is interpreted as the local date **in the local time zone**.

This is probably related to what you're observing.

To eliminate time and time zone concerns you might wish to either work with the `LocalDate` directly, thus simply dropping all time-related concerns on the floor, or deliberately converting to some well-known-for-your-system time zone.  The class that may help you out here is [`java.time.ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).  Hope this is helpful.

Comment: While what you say is true and would certainly be helpful to some, it doesn’t seem to bear much relation to the issue asked about here.

Answer (score 2):

The other two Answers are correct. I’ll add a few more thoughts.

## `java.sql.Date` is obsolete

The terrible class `java.sql.Date` was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

These is no need to ever use `java.sql.Date` again.  Now replaced by `java.time.LocalDate`. With JDBC 4.2 and later, we can exchange *java.time* objects with the database.

Write to database.

```
LocalDate ld = myDatePicker.getValue() ;  // Extract `LocalDate` from JavaFX widget.
myPreparedDatabase.setObject( … , ld ) ;  // Write to database.
```

Retrieve from database.

```
LocalDate ld =  myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

## Convert

If you absolutely must have a `java.sql.Date` to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, convert. Look to new methods added to the old classes.

```
java.sql.Date myJSD = Date.valueOf( myLocalDate ) ;
```

Going the other direction.

```
LocalDate myLocalDate = myJSD.toLocalDate() ;
```